# Issue with passing params, and constantize/uppercase two different words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Having a slight issue getting a simple param to constantize properly.   The model is "BackTricks".

This line is instantiating the variable fine with single word models, although in this particular situation it renders the variable as "Backtricks" without casing the second word properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
      klass       = params[:klass].to_s.capitalize.singularize.constantize
```

Comment: what is inside `params[:klass]` ?

Comment: klass just contains params,  which would be something like  api/test/:klass   :klass being a word that would match a particular model.. this works fine on models that are single words, but an issue with an example like above that is two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `titelize` instead of `capitalize`

Comment: doesterr.. thanks for the suggestion although unfortunately that didn't seem to impact the case of the second word

Comment: so for example to help further, (this doesn't work, because we need to captilize both the "b" and the "t".) :backtricks.to_s.titleize.singularize.constantize  -- (this does work, because we only need to capitalize the "m") :model.to_s.titleize.singularize.constantize

Comment: I don't think it's easily possible to detect that these are in fact two words. If you can use a seperator, e.g. `back_tricks` it would be a lot easier :) `:foo_bar.to_s.titleize.delete(" ") #=> "FooBar"`

Answer (score 1):

If `params[:klass]` is a snake_cased string, you can use `classify` instead of `capitalize.singularize`:

```
'egg_and_hams'.classify # => "EggAndHam"
'posts'.classify        # => "Post"
```

[Source](http://apidock.com/rails/String/classify)